# How can I change checkbox value using jQuery depending on checkbox checked or not?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

if checkbox checked value will be 1 if not checked value will be 0

I can be able to get is checked or not but can't change value if checked value will be 1 if not checked value will be 0

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" value="0" class="custom-control-input" name="is_Current" id="isCurrentExperience">
```

Current

jQuery

```
$('#isCurrentExperience').change(function () {
        if ($('#isCurrentExperience').is(':checked') == true){
            $('#endDate').val('').prop('disabled', true);
            //console.log('checked');
        } else {
            console.log($('#isCurrentExperience').val('0'));
            $('#endDate').val('').prop('disabled', false);
            //console.log('unchecked');
        }
    });
```

But also need to change value after checked or not checked.

Comment: Can't you just not add `.val('1')`?

Comment: What exactly you want? You want to make input disabled when it is checked and remove disable when it is not checked?

Comment: just add value when checkbox is checked, currenlty `$('#endDate').val('')` is in both cases so no value will be added

Comment: I want to disable #endDate and set value 1 or 0 while checked and unchecked.

Comment: Thanks all for contributions. Solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the value like `$('#isCurrentExperience').val('0');` OR `$('#isCurrentExperience').val('1');` depends on your requirement. see the solution below

```js
$('#isCurrentExperience').change(function () {
        if ($('#isCurrentExperience').is(':checked') == true){
           $('#isCurrentExperience').val('1');
           //other things
            console.log('checked');
        } else {
           $('#isCurrentExperience').val('0');
           //other things
            console.log('unchecked');
        }
        
        console.log("CURRENT VALUE IS: "+$('#isCurrentExperience').val())
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="0" class="custom-control-input" name="is_Current" id="isCurrentExperience">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work with `.val()` function on checkbox to change the value from 0 to 1 or vice versa.
Also, please make sure that you bind change event handler to checkbox once all DOM is ready hence use 'doucument.ready' which will ensure DOM loaded
Please see below code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#isCurrentExperience').on('change', function(){
          var value = $(this).is(':checked')?'1':'0';
          $(this).val(value); // set value as per checked status
          console.log($(this).val());//print value
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="0" class="custom-control-input" name="is_Current" id="isCurrentExperience">
```

Answer (score -1):

Best way ternary :

```
onclick="this.value = this.value === '1' ? '0' : '1'"
```